# In tmux I only have 2 groups

Tags: tmux, usergroups

In `tmux` I only have 2 groups, as opposed to the expected 5:

```
$ groups
username sudo staff website1 website2
$ tmux

$ groups
username sudo
```

Why is this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Perhaps your tmux server was started before you were added to the additional groups.  The server process and any processes which it starts will only have the permissions that were in place when the server was started.

You can fix this by closing all sessions and starting a new server.  Once you've quit any programs that you care about which are running inside tmux sessions you can use `tmux kill-server` to ensure that the old server process is ended.  Then when you run tmux again it will automatically start a new server which should have all of your current permissions.